# Specify user's home directory in a .properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, p6spy

I am trying to integrate p6spy (3.x.x) in my project, and in `spy.properties` file, I wanted to specify

```
logfile=${user.home}/logs/spy-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
```

or at least

```
logfile=${user.home}/logs/spy.log
```

So far, I couldn't manage to do either, and the execution is failing with `FileNotFoundException`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${user.home}/logs/spy.log (No such file or directory)
```

Mine is a Spring Boot project with collaborators running different operating systems. By default, it is creating the `spy.log` file in project root, which is not good.

Is it possible to specify relative paths like the way I want in .properties files? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P6spy does not support placeholders. That's why ${user.home} is not recognized, you can try p6spy-spring-boot-starter from my library https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator that integrates p6spy into spring boot allowing you to use application.properties/yml where placeholders are supported instead of spy.properties.

You should put this into your application properties: 

`decorator.datasource.p6spy.logging=file
decorator.datasource.p6spy.log-file=${user.home}/logs/spy.log`

But if you want to have rotating of the logs it's better to use slf4j and add custom appender to your logging library to capture only p6spy logs.